# Does opencascad(OCCT) itself support cell picking like CAD Assistant?

Tags: opencascade

As we can see:

[image: cad assistant cell picking]

Within the OCCT based CAD Assistant,user can mouse over a single cell to get it's detailed information and highlight it,question are?

```
1,Does OCCT itself support this operation?

2,If yes,any example or tips to pick a cell and retrieve it's information (such as cell id,cell color)?
```

-------------Update---------------------
Under OCCT 7.6,vstate produce nothing,like this:
[image: vstate produces nothing]

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to collect some answers.

First of all, you will not find in OCCT exactly the same shape presentation as on your screenshot. This custom presentation is likely based on `AIS_ColoredShape` with extra features on top.

OCCT has a dedicated class for displaying mesh structures like [`MeshVS_Mesh`](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_user_guides__visualization.html#occt_visu_5). It supports mesh elements selection out of the box, though you'll have to implement a special data source interface to feed mesh data to it.

[image: MeshVS_Mesh triangle selection]

As for standard Shape presentations like `AIS_Shape`/`AIS_ColoredShape`, they don't implement highlighting of individual triangles. But you may retrieve information about last detected triangle via standard selection mechanisms like `Select3D_SensitiveTriangulation::LastDetectedTriangleIndex()`. You may find code sample retrieving this information from source code of Draw Harness command `vstate` in `src/ViewerTest/ViewerTest.cxx`. The following Tcl script:

```
pload MODELING VISUALIZATION
box b 1 2 3
vinit View1
vdisplay -dispMode 1 b
vfit
vmoveto 250 200
vstate -entities
```

produces the following output:

```
Detected entities:
  b  Depth: 1.34919 Distance: 1.46373 Point: 1 1.08384 1.74698 Normal: 1 0 0 (Select3D_SensitiveTriangulation)
     Detected Shape: TopoDS_TSolid
     Detected Triangle: 2
```

The [following article](https://unlimited3d.wordpress.com/2021/11/16/ais-object-computing-selection/) might be helpful in learning how to implement `AIS` object subclass with own features like custom dynamic highlighting. Within custom object you may retrieve triangle info out of detected `Select3D_SensitiveTriangulation` and draw it in the viewer on dynamic highlighting object on mouse move.

Comment: Thanks,where does your sample image come from?Any sample project can produce it?

Comment: The image is a screenshot of Draw Harness window for a test case coming with OCCT (e.g. `test v3d mesh bug26028 1`) that loads STL file and displays it as `MeshVS_Mesh` presentation.

Comment: Under OCCT 7.6，vstate produce nothing